# How to Print Output Stream of Gradle BuildLauncher Live and Line-by-line

Tags: java, inputstream, outputstream, gradle-plugin

I am using the Gradle Tooling API to programatically execute build tasks. For this I am using the BuildLauncher and running .forTasks("clean") on it. I would like to print the Standard Output and Standard Error in real time line by line.

I have been able to print the entire Standard Output but only once the build process is done using the code below.

```java
// connector already created and set up

ProjectConnection connection = connector.connect();
BuildLauncher build = connection.newBuild();
build.forTasks("clean");

ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

build.setStandardOutput(outputStream);
build.setStandardError(outputStream);

build.run();

System.out.println(outputStream.toString());

connection.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a solution and am answering my own question in case anyone stumbles upon it.

The key was to override the write() method when creating a new OutputStream object. The code below prints everything live and line-by-line to System.out but can easily be changed to print to a GUI, tool window (which is what I am doing), or anywhere else.

```java
// connector already created and set up

ProjectConnection connection = connector.connect();
BuildLauncher build = connection.newBuild();
build.forTasks("clean");

OutputStream outputStream = new OutputStream() {
            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                System.out.print((char) b); // or output it to anywhere else you'd like
            }
        };

build.setStandardOutput(outputStream);
build.setStandardError(outputStream);

build.run();

connection.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
build.setStandardOutput(System.out);
build.setStandardError(System.err);
```